# Listing ArcSDE versions using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I have an ArcSDE geodatabase with different versions for each user.

How can I list each version using ArcPy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a function on arcpy called ListVersions.
Here's [online help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/ListVersions/000v0000001v000000/) for it.

```
    >>> print (arcpy.ListVersions('bigiron.sde'))
    [u'BILLY.VersionOne', u'JOE.2B8E86', u'S.DEFAULT']
    >>>
```