# How to get specific version (renedered with) of a feature layer in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, sql-server, versioning

Is there any way to get version of a layer loaded using `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management` in arcpy with mssql server connection. There are tools that be used for several types of version related tasks like `arcpy.ChangeVersion_management`, `arcpy.CreateVersionedView_management` etc. but i want to know is there any way to know version of the that temporary layer in arcpy.

I tried [Listing ArcSDE versions using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60339/listing-arcsde-versions-using-arcpy) but it gives all the version in a sde connection- but i want to know specifically with which version layer is loaded.So i do not want `arcpy.ListVersions(r'Database Connections\MSSQLSERVER.sde')`

I tried `arcpy.Describe` but all in vain.

Below is the pseudocode-

```
arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management("path","Test1.sde","SQL_SERVER","instance","DATABASE_AUTH","user","pass","SAVE_USERNAME","sde__my","#","TRANSACTIONAL","DBO.Test1","#")

Above line does not change the version to "DBO.Test1" if i run as above but if i run the gui tool it works perfectly so i need to check if version changed.


mywrk = r"path\Test1.sde"
fc_cor1 = r'path\Test1.sde\sde__my.DBO.FIPS2900\sde__my.DBO.testfc_1'
fc_cor2 = r'path\Test1.sde\sde__my.DBO.FIPS2900\sde__my.DBO.testfc'


arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_cor1,'fc1')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_cor2,'fc2')

Now i want to know if version of 'fc1' and 'fc2' is DBO.Test1 otherwise change as below-

try:
    arcpy.ChangeVersion_management("fc1","TRANSACTIONAL","DBO.Test1")
    arcpy.ChangeVersion_management("fc2","TRANSACTIONAL","DBO.Test1")
except:
    pass
```

[image: demo]

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and MSSQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to obtain the map layer object first -

```
fl = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc,"out_fl")
map_layer = fl.getOutput(0)
map_layer.serviceProperties['Version']
>>> u'sde.DEFAULT'
```

which has the `serviceProperties` property - a dictionary containing all the information related to the connection including, but not limited to the version name.